# pdftex: where to get prebuilt binaries for win32?

Tags: pdftex

I've used [PDFTeX](http://www.tug.org/applications/pdftex/) in the past, and I remember just downloading the binaries for Windows systems. Now I have a new computer and I went to download it, but there's only the source package. Where can I download a prebuild binary for win32?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe they are providing them any more.  You might consider trying [Lyx](http://www.lyx.org/Home).  It's a simplified Latex editor that include a [pdflatex](http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/PDF#toc17) tool that does the same thing as pdftex.  The Lyx [windows installer](http://www.lyx.org/Download#toc3) is only 22 MB.

It will go out and install MikTex for you if you have no latex installed already - MikTex tops the scales at about 100 MB.  There are no 'small' latex packages, primarily because of all the font files installed.  Do you already have latex installed?  How are you expecting to use pdftex with out a compiler to feed it??

Comment: Thanks. I don't really want to use any of this, I'm just trying to generate PDF from Sphinx reStructuredText files, and it only does this through producing latex as an intermediate step. I went ahead and just installed MikTex.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html

This does include pdftex, see http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc.html

Comment: hmmm... where does this say it includes pdftex, and how large is the installation? I don't want to install MiKTeX, it's 100MB+ and I just need the PDFTeX part.

Comment: UGH, it's 173MB just for the "basic" TeX and I still can't figure out if it includes PDFTeX. Thanks but no thanks.

Comment: I don't think that you will find a windows binary for **just PDFTeX**. And (like *DaveParillo* said) how do you want to use this without a (La)TeX system anyway?

Comment: well, +1 for giving me useful information anyway.